# Mostrar un mensaje de error si no obtiene el resultado del filtro JS

Tags: javascript, css, transacciones, selectores-css

Quiero mostrar un mensaje de error cuando se este filtrando y no encuentre una propiedad que existe, también quiero incluir un spinner mientras busco los datos. Y si es posible una pequeña transición al mostrar los datos filtrados de las tarjetas.

Agradecería muchísimo la ayuda!

JS:

```javascript
const filterProducts = [...document.querySelectorAll(".card")]; // cast to array type
const type = document.getElementById("select__type");
const category = document.getElementById("select__category");
const city = document.getElementById("select__city");
const fromField = document.querySelector(".filters__price--prev input");
const toField = document.querySelector(".filters__price--next input");
const getPrice = (str) => str.replace(/[\$ ,]/g, "");
document
   .getElementById("properties__filters")
   .addEventListener("change", function(e) {
       const typ = type.value;
       const cat = category.value;
       const cit = city.value;
       let from = +fromField.value;
       let to = +toField.value;
       if (to === 0) { to = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY; }

       console.log(typ, cat, cit);

       filterProducts.forEach((card) => {
          const price = getPrice(
            card.querySelector(".content__price--money").textContent
          );
          console.log(from, price, to);
          const show =
            (typ === "." || card.dataset.type === typ) &&
            (cat === "." || card.dataset.category === cat) &&
            (cit === "." || card.dataset.city === cit) &&
            from <= price &&
            to >= price;
          card.classList.toggle("hide", !show);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Hay algún proceso asíncrono en tu código? Si no lo hay, no veo la necesidad de un spinner

Comment: No lo hay, pero ha futuro lo implementaré por ello deseaba saberlo...